# Why the carriage return character is not considered as a white space character by the preprocessor

Tags: c, whitespace, language-lawyer, preprocessor

In the section `6.4 Lexical elements` of the C Standard there is written

> 3. ... Preprocessing tokens can be separated by white space; this consists of
>      comments (described later), or white-space characters
>      (space, horizontal tab, new-line, vertical tab, and form-feed), or
>      both.

As it is seen the carriage return character is not included in the notion of the white space characters.

On the other hand in the description of the standard C function `isspace` there is written (`7.4.1.10 The isspace function`)

> 3. ...The standard white-space characters are the following: space (''), form feed ('\f'), new-line ('\n'), **carriage return ('\r')**,
>      horizontal tab ('\t'), and vertical tab ('\v'). In the "C" locale,
>      isspace returns true only for the standard white-space characters.

Is it intentionally that the carriage return character is not mentioned in the section describing preprocessing and if so what is the reason?

Or is it  just a Standard's defect?

The same questions are valid for the C++ Standard.

Comment: Otherwise the preprocessor cannot know where the statement ends. And is why \ is used to show it *does* continue on the next line.

Comment: Note that §5.1.1.2 Translation phases has step _1. Physical source file multibyte characters are mapped, in an implementation-defined
manner, to the source character set (introducing new-line characters for
end-of-line indicators) if necessary._  If the source file has CRLF line endings, this step could map those to newline (LF) characters if the CRLF line ending is recognized by the source environment.  Thus, on Windows, that mapping is appropriate.  It isn't strictly appropriate on Unix, but could be supported by a generous compiler, possibly under user guidance from a command-line option.

Comment: @WeatherVane There are no statements in the preprocessing stage.  If you are talking about preprocessing directives, they are terminated by newlines, not carriage returns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 5.2.1 paragraph 3.

The carriage return character is a member of the basic execution character set (and it treated by `isspace()` as a white-space character), but it's not part of the basic source character set.

The source and execution basic character sets both include "the space character, and control characters representing horizontal tab, vertical tab, and form feed". In addition, "In the basic execution character set, there shall be control characters representing alert, backspace, carriage return, and new line".

On some systems, the carriage return character is part of the indication of an end-of-line; any such indication is treated as a single new-line. A carriage return character that's *not* part of an end-of-line indicator in a source file causes undefined behavior.

Comment: And what is the reason of excluding the carriage return character from the basic character set?

Comment: What purpose would it serve to translating the source that a new-line does not provide?

Comment: @Keith Thompson  That is there is some inconsistence between the preprocessing and the behavior of the C standard function isspace.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: The carriage return is excluded from the basic *source* character set. It's included in the basic *execution* character set. I can't speak for the committee, but since end-of-line markers in source files are treated as newline characters, there's no particular reason to allow for them in source files. Since the behavior is undefined, any particular compiler is free to treat them any way it likes. Yes, there's an inconsistency, but in this case I see no particular advantage in being consistent.

Comment: In order to escape a newline, the \ character must immediately precede it, without any intervening whitespace.  If a carriage return were considered a whitespace character, systems which use cr+lf as a line separator would see a \ at the end of the line as having a cr (whitespace) character before the newline.  If instead the system seems cr as the first character of a newline sequence, then escaped newlines will work.  BTW, I suspect many implementations use the same model of newline handling as Adobe PostScript, where either CR or LF will be a newline except that CR will be ignored...

Comment: ...when preceded by a non-ignored LF, and LF will be ignored when preceded by a non-ignored CR.

Answer (score 3):

The source file input gets translated into the source character set (translation phase 1 in §5.1.1.2 of the standard). The source character set is described in §5.2.1.

In C.2011, §5.2.1¶3:

> In source files, there shall be some way of indicating the end of
>   each line of text; this International Standard treats such an end-of-line indicator as if it were a single new-line character.

A bare carriage return is not part of the source character set. If it appears as part of a line termination sequence, it gets translated into a single new-line before the C preprocessor begins to do its work.